# How to make drop down content 100%?

Tags: css

Peace,
I use this drop-down code.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

And I want mobile content to be wide: 100%;

The problem is that the content is aligned to the button and I want it to be full screen

What can I do?

[the content is aligned to the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mYQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following, and you should be good to go.

```
.dropdown-content {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

It depends, of course, which parent element is set to `position:relative`. Another way to achieve the top position would be to use `position:fixed` instead of the absolute positioning.

Comment: Thank you... I did 
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 35px;
        position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

just change this:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

to:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

if you just want that for mobile use a media query

Comment: First of all, thank you

I did that ... the problem is that ther content is aligned to the button and is not across the entire page. I edited the question and added a picture